# In Python (Pandas/Numpy) How can I subset a df conditional on a timedelta value?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the one below where the column 'Duration' is:

```
df['Duration'] = df['DateTime A'] - df['DateTime B']

Name: Duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

             DateTime A         A           DateTime B         B          Duration
19  2010-01-29 16:39:00  124.7812  2010-02-03 16:19:00  121.9688  4 days, 23:40:00
27  2010-02-08 16:31:00  124.8438  2010-02-10 13:24:00  121.9062  1 days, 20:53:00
29  2010-02-10 20:31:00  123.0938  2010-02-11 13:02:00  120.5625  0 days, 16:31:00
73  2010-04-02 08:31:00  120.1875  2010-04-05 13:38:00  117.4375  3 days, 05:07:00
99  2010-05-05 09:39:00  128.1875  2010-05-06 08:01:00  125.9375  0 days, 22:22:00
```

I want to filter/subset the dataframe conditionally on the value of the 'Duration' column, I tried a lot of different things,

```
sample = df[df['Duration'] < '1days']                           TypeError: invalid type comparison
sample = df[df['Duration'] < timedelta('1 days')]               TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: str
sample = df[df['Duration'] < Timedelta(timedelta('1 days'))]    NameError: name 'Timedelta' is not defined
```

I'm aware of some changes about this on pandas 0.15. However I'm working with pandas 0.14.1.

Thanks

Comment: your above code will work in 0.15; in 0.14.1 you will need to use datetime.timedelta or np.timedelta64 objects directly (instead of the strings that represent timedelta eg '1 days')